# ad inserter plugin doesnt show ads from server

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins

I'm making a WordPress site, and want to show the same ads that were used on my old site blue circle.DK but when I use the same javascript in the plugin ad inserter the ads don't show.

this is the code im using:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ad1.emediate.dk/EAS_tag.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
EAS_load_fif("EAS_fif_798", null, "//ad1.emediate.dk/eas?cu=798;cre=mu;js=y;pageviewid=;target=_blank", 468, 60);
</script>
```

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the new site on a different server? If so I would imagine you would need to let "emediate" know that the site has moved. I'm not familiar with them but do you have access to a dashboard where you can change settings?

Comment: hey, thanks for you comment, i completly forgot i asked in here, i´m new to the site. I don't know much about how serving ads work, but from what it sounds like is that this ad company needs to change which site the ads are served to before the js can work? I only have access to the wordpress settings, but i'm in contact with the guy serving the ads.

Comment: Okay cool. I would imagine that you need to get a new snippet of javascript from the guy serving the ads so. Have a chat with him and see how you get on.

Comment: Will do that, thanks so much for the help!

Comment: No problem. Let me know if I'm correct and I'll post as an answer and you can mark as answered. Cheers!